# Creating root folders without files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been trying like crazy to make a context menu based 'folder only' copier. This is very much like xcopy /T /E, but xcopy doesn't let you copy the main directory. It only copies the sub-directories (I think?)

So I have a program that will let me highlight certain folders and pass them as args to a batch script and I can iterate through them. The problem I have is everything is getting evaluated as the first arg. I end up having the first folder trying to create itself several times.

Here was the full script I envisioned. Note I never really got around to the 2nd part where I let xcopy do the job of filling in the sub-directories like normal. I just hit a wall trying to create the root directories. That is the most crucial thing to me. xcopy from the previously directory isn't viable, because I only want **CERTAIN FOLDERS** created:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


md "copy of folders"
cd "copy of folders"

for %%x in (%*) do (
   echo %%x
   ::^ this will give me all the args full paths as it iterates
   md "%~n1"
   ::^ this retrieves folder name, but its always the first argument's folder name, it doesn't iterate
)

pause

for %%x in (%*) do (
   xcopy %%x "%cd%" /T /E
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 md "%~n1"
```

which creates a directory from the name part of parameter 1

to

```
 md %%~nxx
```

which creates a directory from the name-and-extension parts of the current value of the metavariable %%x.

Not sure where you're going with the `xcopy`. You appear to want to copy the tree from the newly-created (and hence empty) directory to the current directory `"copy of folders"`

---

Here's my full test batch. I use `U:` for test data.

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

PUSHD U:\

md "copy of folders"
cd "copy of folders"

dir
ECHO ============================
for %%x in (%*) do (
  echo %%x
rem  ::^ this will give me all the args full paths as it iterates
  md %%~nxx
rem  ::^ this retrieves folder name, but its always the first argument's folder name, it doesn't iterate
)

DIR
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's my test results, using *thisbatch "U:\path" "u:\path2" path3*

```
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0460-0000

 Directory of U:\copy of folders

05/08/2014  10:56    <DIR>          .
05/08/2014  10:56    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,146,893,824 bytes free
============================
"U:\path"
"U:\path2"
"PATH3"
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0460-0000

 Directory of U:\copy of folders

05/08/2014  10:56    <DIR>          .
05/08/2014  10:56    <DIR>          ..
05/08/2014  10:56    <DIR>          path
05/08/2014  10:56    <DIR>          path2
05/08/2014  10:56    <DIR>          PATH3
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)   2,146,795,520 bytes free
```

Note that the `::` comment mathod is in fact a broken label - it can cause problems in a block statement (parenthesised series of statements) hence should be replaced by `REM`

If you want to create directories relative to the current (copy of folders) then you use ~nxx. If you want those directories created using a full path as you state in your comment, then the current directory is irrelevant and you should use `"%%~fx"` (including the quotes).

The quotes are not required unless you are including a separator (line a space) in the name to be created, when the quotes become required.

Comment: This still is only creating 1 folder name out of a selection of folders passed as args eg "c:/path" "c:/path2" "c:/path3"

I mean to use the xcopy as it would usually be used. It would fill the copied root dir names which are placed in "copy of folders" on the same tier with the root folders that were copied. eg:

"c:/path"
"c:/path2"
"c:/path3"
"c:/copy of folders/path1"
"c:/copy of folders/path2"
"c:/copy of folders/path3"